# Custom post type pagination - always return first page

Tags: custom-post-types, pagination

I have custom post template archive-product.php for custom post type "product".

In this template paging does not work:

- numbers are displayed
- all numbers links redirect to first page

  ```
      <?php if (($numParent) == 4) {?>

      do stuff

      <?php } elseif (($numParent) == 3) { 

          $paged = 1;  
          if ( get_query_var('paged') ) $paged = get_query_var('paged');  
          if ( get_query_var('page') ) $paged = get_query_var('page'); 
          query_posts = array('post_parent'=> $post->ID, 'post_type'=>'product','paged' => $paged, 'posts_per_page' => 10); 
          while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();?>

              do stuff

          <?php endwhile; ?>
          <?php if ( function_exists( 'wp_pagenavi' ) ) {
              wp_pagenavi();
          }; 
      } endif;?>
  ```

How to fix paging?

Comment: How do you fetch the posts before the first `have_posts()` call?

Comment: there are just header.php and sidebar.php before the first have_posts().

Comment: So you don’t even set the main query? Pagination _cannot_ work as you expect it. Read [about query_posts()](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/1753/73) and its alternatives to see the difference.